# Как сделать шестиугольник с закругленными краями с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filter, css-shapes

Это мой CSS:

```
#hexagon-circle { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 55px; 
    background: red; 
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;} 
#hexagon-circle:before { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -25px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 29px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;} 
#hexagon-circle:after { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -25px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 29px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;}
```

На выходе получается 4 закругленных угла шестиугольника, а вот верхний и нижний углы не получились.
Я хочу сделать все углы шестиугольника закругленными.
Как сделать так, чтобы все углы были закруглены?

[http://jsfiddle.net/yR7zt/1](http://jsfiddle.net/yR7zt/)

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to make a curved edge hexagon by using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24819717/7394871) от участника  [@sooko1005](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3838007/sooko1005).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/24819717/7394871

Comment: Обратите внимание на эту классную штуку. У вас есть фигуры в CSS или SVG с острыми гранями и вдруг заказчик захотел те же фигуры, но закругленными краями. **Ничего не надо переделывать**  Нужно добавить только несколько строчек  SVG фильтров. Не обязательно разбираться в SVG фильтрах. Просто копируйте примеры применения.

Answer (score 3):

### Вариант SVG Shapes + svg filter  feColorMatrix

Берем svg `path` для 8-ми угольной звезды с *острыми лучами*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
   
  <path  d="m200.1 27.9 32.7 91.9 88.1-41.9-41.9 88.1 91.9 32.7-91.9 32.7 41.9 88.1L232.8 277.5 200.1 369.4 167.5 277.5 79.4 319.4 121.3 231.3 29.4 198.7 121.3 166 79.4 77.9 167.5 119.8Z" style="fill:crimson;"/>
</svg>
```

Добавляем  комбинацию фильтров: `feColorMatrix` и

`feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>`
Обратите внимание на значение оператора `atop`

***и после применения фильтров лучи закругляются***

```html
   



<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
   <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
  <path filter="url(#goo)" d="m200.1 27.9 32.7 91.9 88.1-41.9-41.9 88.1 91.9 32.7-91.9 32.7 41.9 88.1L232.8 277.5 200.1 369.4 167.5 277.5 79.4 319.4 121.3 231.3 29.4 198.7 121.3 166 79.4 77.9 167.5 119.8Z" style="fill:crimson;"/>
</svg>
```

**operator="xor"**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
   <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 19 -9"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="xor"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
  <path filter="url(#goo)" d="m200.1 27.9 32.7 91.9 88.1-41.9-41.9 88.1 91.9 32.7-91.9 32.7 41.9 88.1L232.8 277.5 200.1 369.4 167.5 277.5 79.4 319.4 121.3 231.3 29.4 198.7 121.3 166 79.4 77.9 167.5 119.8Z" style="fill:crimson;"/>
</svg>
```

**Обводка контура**

*operator="xor" и  0 0 0 29 -1*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
   <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="xor"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
  <path filter="url(#goo)" d="m200.1 27.9 32.7 91.9 88.1-41.9-41.9 88.1 91.9 32.7-91.9 32.7 41.9 88.1L232.8 277.5 200.1 369.4 167.5 277.5 79.4 319.4 121.3 231.3 29.4 198.7 121.3 166 79.4 77.9 167.5 119.8Z" style="fill:crimson;"/>
</svg>
```

**Рамка с внутренними закругленными уголками**

Берём за основу прямоугольник в SVG или CSS

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
           width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="300" height="200"  fill="crimson" />
</svg>
```

Добавляем фильтр `feColorMatrix` с параметрами матрицы `0 0 0 22 -14`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
           width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  
     <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="16" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix"
                values="
                  0 0 0 0 0
                  0 0 0 0 0
                  0 0 0 0 0
                  0 0 0 22 -14"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="xor"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>

<rect x="50" y="50" width="300" height="200" filter="url(#goo)" fill="crimson" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я рассмотрю тот же трюк, который использовал в [предыдущем ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485455/8620333).
Я буду делать шестиугольник с помощью `clip-path`.

```css
.hex {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:orange;
}

.hex::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background:currentColor;
  padding-top: 90%;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex"></div>
```

Затем я применю фильтр SVG:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.hex {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:orange;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.hex::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background:currentColor;
  padding-top: 86.6%; /* 100%*cos(30) */
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex" style="color:blue;width:150px;"></div>
<div class="hex" style="color:red;width:100px;"></div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

И в обратном направлении:

```css
.hex {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
  color:orange;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.hex::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background:currentColor;
  padding-top: 115%; /* 100%/cos(30)  */
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex"></div>
<div class="hex" style="color:blue;width:150px;"></div>
<div class="hex" style="color:red;width:100px;"></div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504158/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, вы это ищете:

**CSS**

```
.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 10em; height: 17.32em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: orange;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.hex:before, .hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.hex:before {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);/*Added for IE9*/
   transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hex:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);/*Added for IE9*/
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/W2N4C/7/)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819880/7394871) от участника  [@Alex Char](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3420271/alex-char).</sub>

Comment: плюсики поставил - но на svg закруглить эти углы без топорных (path ) можно как то ?

Comment: @MaximLensky наверное можно. Попробую как ни будь

Comment: маекнёшь мне - ок ?

Comment: @MaximLensky смотри вариант svg path + svg filter

Comment: я не увидел - где этот шестиугоьник без path ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Значит я тебя не понял. Предыдущие варианты были фигуры CSS и их закругляли фильтрами. Я так понял, что ты хотел закруглять фильтрами SVG фигуры

Comment: я имел ввиду - такой шестиугольник сделать без path потому что на path я умею ... я думал можно как то

Comment: @MaximLensky ну если без path, то это тебе в CSS - градиенты, бордеры clip-path .... Тут же речь шла о классной фиче - Закруглении углов на уже готовых `path`вместо прорисовки новыми path