# Как сделать трапецию с закруглёнными углами?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такую трапецию? Спасибо

Comment: SVG на фон и не парьтесь..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На css такой вариант.. Лучше конечно SVG использовать.

```css
.decor {
  width: 250px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #9732CC;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.scroller {
  scrollbar-width: none;  /*скрыть scroll в fireFox*/
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .7em;
  /* width: 0; /*скрыть scroll*\/ */
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#boxContent {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 278px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -17px;
  clip-path: polygon(7% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-align: center;
}

#box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 90px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background: #9732CC;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="boxContent" class="decor scroller">Lorem r sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exemco laboris nisi ut aliquip Lorem r sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exemco laboris nisi ut aliquip</div>
<div id="box" class="decor"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы задать форму можно использовать `clip-path: polygon`, но вот как сделать корректные кругления - увы не знаю

А вообще если бы у меня была такая задача, то воспользовался бы SVG

Подробнее - [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250120/Как-сделать-шестиугольник-с-закругленными-краями-с-помощью-css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250120/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-css)

Есть ещё такое решение - https://codepen.io/Grilly86/pen/gWodKV